# Android Logcat not showing Application Logging Messages on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos

I have two testing environments: a Linux Ubuntu 2016 and a Mac OS X 10.8 (Lion).
I don't use Android Studio Debugging console.
I generate the app-release.apk and deploy it on my test phone (AZUS).
I then use the command line tool adb (sudo adb logcat) to access the Application Debug log.
On my Linux test environment, everything works fine: the logs show up pretty well.
On my Mac OS X, nothing shows except the FATAL exceptions.
Is there any configurations I need to setup for the logging with lower priority to show up on ADB?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
It was necessary to add the following to the App level build.gradle

```
android{
 buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
    }
  } }
```